# coffeescript while/ loop / for multiple statements in beautiful coffee

Tags: javascript, for-loop, coffeescript

I have been using something like :

```
n = 50
force.tick() for i in [0...n]
```

but I am trying to find a way to do multiple statments with 50 times as able

```
n = 50
force.tick() 
doSomthing1
doSomething2
    for i in [0...n]
```

This obviously does not work, Is there a way to do somethign simliar this above query in coffeescript ?

Answer (score 4):

Just regular [loop syntax](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) instead of a single-line-comprehension:

```
n = 50
for i in [0...n]
    force.tick()
    doSomthing1
    doSomething2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(force.tick();doSomthing1();doSomthing2()) for i in [0...n]
```